# Mapping a localStorage variable (an Array of Objects) refuses to work/causes item to disappear

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapping, appery.io

I have an array in my localStorage, product_categories, which holds numerous objects which contain a string and a nested array of objects (the inner objects are the products that belong to each category).

Since Appery's support couldn't help me figure out how to query an array of objects based on an attribute belonging to each object - I just made each object (product) belong to an array and categorize the products based on which array index they were.

Anyway, I am now trying to map an array of objects to my page's collapsible block, which I have done previously - but with a response from the online database.

Now, I am using a SEPARATE service and all I want it to do is grab the array of objects from the localStorage and map it to a collapsible block, or even a grid or list item, so that each index in the array auto-creates a new item.

However, it has not worked for anything I have tried. I tried to map it to every possible item that can have arrays mapped to it, and when I load the page - the item actually disappears, almost as if the array being mapped to it has a length of 0.

But, when I inspect the page in Chrome and look at the localStorage variable that is being used to hold the array of objects (and in-turn mapped to the page), the variable clearly has an array of objects in the same format as other localStorage variables being mapped to the page from storage.

If it helps, I am using a GenericService for pulling the localStorage variables and mapping them to the page. I am not using a custom implementation - all the service does is 'ON SUCCESS - MAPPING' and maps the storage to the page. However, like I said, this isn't working.

Since I have been here for a while but never actually posted or anything, I don't have the rep to post the images that may help in solving my problem; with that in mind, here is the link to the original Appery.io support page which contains corresponding images: https://getsatisfaction.com/apperyio/topics/mapping-localstorage-array-to-collapsible-wont-work-removes-collapsible-item

StackOverflow, I would really appreciate your assistance as I always seem to run into a language barrier when working with Appery.io's support.

*EDIT Your revisions are not useful for my post, as they are changing localStorage to local storage - but in the case of Appery, localStorage is correct syntax.

```
var products = offlineProductList(); // grab the returned JSON array of products from the function offlineProductList()
var UniqueCats = $.unique(products.map(function (d) { 
    return d.category // this will return every distinct category
}));

var product_categories = []; // create empty array to hold each category object and its respective products

for(var i=0;i<UniqueCats.length;i++){

    // for every unique category...
    var category_products = []; // create array to hold products

    for(var j=0;j<products.length;j++){

        // run through list of products

        if(products[j].category == UniqueCats[i]){

            // if the product's category is the same as the current indexed unique category, add to array
            category_products.push(products[j]);


        }

    }
    var category = {"category":UniqueCats[i],"category_products":category_products}; // create object for the category
    product_categories.push(category); // add object to the categorical array

}
localStorage.setItem('product_categories', JSON.stringify(product_categories));
```

Above is the code used to create the 'array of objects', and below is an image showing the mapping

[array of objects mapping to an appery page element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5ydy.png)

I would give you more but SO won't allow me to with my rep. So if you ask for more I might just 404 myself

Comment: Please be specific and share your code highlighting the part of snippet which is causing the problem

Comment: @brk that is as specific as I can be man, I really don't know how much more specific I could be. If you could look more into the question that would be excellent.

Comment: Also, for future responders - I feel as if the code snippet is only going to confuse you with what the problem I'm having is. It is the MAPPING that I am having an issue with. I can almost assure the code itself isn't the issue.

Comment: @MattYates For future questions : please be less wordy. Wordiness doesn't make things clearer nor more specific.

Comment: While everyone is complaining about the format or wording of the post, I figured it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out myself - Appery actually offers the option for mapping expressions on events like 'Page Load' (for pages/panels etc) and 'Click' (for buttons and similar elements), and I was succesfully able to map localStorage arrays to list, collapsible, and grid elements from there. I guess my GenericService was set up inproperly - but for future users having issues of just mapping something from Storage to the page - just link a mapping expression from an element's event.